# DLL patching in Click Once application in Windows application .Net Framework

Tags: c#, winforms, clickonce

I have created click once windows application which has multiple dll references (those are actually project references). Windows application contains only forms and controls and business logic resided in dlls. 
Problems is when I change something in dll I have to deploy entire click once application on server. So on client side application gets updated with entire build instead single dll. I tried changing .menifast file by changing dll version and hash as well but it didn't work. 
For any change I want to that particular dll should get downloaded to client based on .manifast file on server.
I am using Visual Studio 2017 and .net Framework 4.7.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Click Once applications support upgrades by deploying the entire application package.
You can't deploy only the updated assemblies.